# HBase: How to specify multiple prefix filters in a single scan operation

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have got the scan result for a given partial row key using prefix filter:

Row key examples: 123_abc, 456_def, 789_ghi

```
var prefix=Bytes.toBytes("123")
var scan = new Scan(prefix)
var prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(prefix)
scan.setFilter(prefixFilter)
var resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan)
```

Now, my question is how can I specify multiple prefix filters that will go as input for the scan operation. The Result object should contain all the rows that have row key value with the given prefix, say 123 or 456.

I have tried the following answer which uses FilterList approach but couldn't get the required result:

[Set Multiple prefix row filter to scanner hbase java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079949/set-multiple-prefix-row-filter-to-scanner-hbase-java)

Any help on this (in Scala or Java) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this [docs of filter list](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) you might have NOT used correct option...

> FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL (AND) or
>   FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE (OR). Since you can use Filter Lists
>   as children of Filter Lists, you can create a hierarchy of filters to
>   be evaluated.  FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL evaluates lazily:
>   evaluation stops as soon as one filter does not include the KeyValue. 
>   FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE evaluates non-lazily: all filters
>   are always evaluated.  Defaults to FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL.

```
 /* FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL by default */
      FilterList allFilters = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);
      allFilters.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("123")));
     allFilters.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("456")));
     allFilters.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("678")));
    scan.setFilter(allFilters);

    var resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan)
```

#### Point to verify :

since You already used `FilterList`, I think you might have used default one i.e `MUST_PASS_ALL` for which all prefix conditions needs to be 
met may be that's why its not giving result.

afore mentioned code should work.. Good luck

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the operator MUST_PASS_ALL. Even though all given prefix values are present in hbase, it's not producing the proper output. But when I use MUST_PASS_ONE, it's working. Can you find out the reason behind this?

Comment: reason is simple in basics of programming like c or any other language ...  true and true is true(`MUST_PASS_ALL` case ). How can a row with same prefix will satisfy all the condtions at the same time. so I used true or true(`MUST_PASS_ONE`); got it?

Comment: A note about the performance of this solution: You are doing a full table scan and putting ALL rows through these filters. In general this is extremely inefficient. With a large table and only a handful of prefixes doing multiple scans using `scan.setRowPrefixFilter(prefix)` may be faster.

Comment: Yes I prefer fuzzyrowfilter for big tables it jumps to maching rows with place Holder. So its faster. I used this for big hbase tables . It works well